# Drupal - Clean up exisiting code that converts text into an image

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've created the following snippet of code within a custom content.tpl.php template

```
<?php
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_youtube_video_link');

if(!empty($field)): ?>
  <div class="youtube-popup">
    <?php

      print "<a class=youtube-play cboxElement href=".$content['field_youtube_video_link']['#object']->field_youtube_video_link['und'][0]['url'].">".$img."</a>";?>
  </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm really wanting to clean this up and rather than do all of this in the content-type.tpl.php I would prefer to do this through a preprocess hook and then create a custom theme template for it, but I'm unsure of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can style by fields. Check out:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions

> Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, listed from
>   the most specific template to the least. Drupal will use the most
>   specific template it finds:
>
> ```
> field--field-name--content-type.tpl.php
> field--content-type.tpl.php
> field--field-name.tpl.php
> field--field-type.tpl.php
> ```